# How do I create an empty data directory with install4j?

Tags: install4j

I used the "Directory selection" screen template to let the user choose a data directory.

I then used the variable from that location to define a distribution tree root:
[image: filetree]

The data dir does not get created. Do I need at least one dummy file inside the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation roots are not created if they do no exist and no files are contained in them. You can add a "Run script" action and set the script to

```
new File((String)context.getVariable("InstallationDataPath")).mkdirs();
return true;
```